# SMD capacitor broke off from motherboatd

Tags: motherboard

While uninstalling the CPU fan (which became so noisy through time, that I decided to replace it) from my ASUS P5K motherboard, I successfully managed to broke off a small part from the motherboard, what looks to me like a small SMD capacitor, but I might be wrong. I marked the area where the capacitor broke off on the following picture:
[image: ASUS P5K motherboard]

After installing the new CPU fan, the computer works great without any noticeable side effect. I read on a site, that some SMD capacitors around the CPU are responsible for reducing noise on channels and the system can live without one missing.

My question is, whether I should be worried about consequences and if yes, what steps could be taken? I am not really into soldiering and do not even have the equipment to repair it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that one side of the component appears to be attached to a ground plane I'd say that most likely it is a [decoupling capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor). However it's impossible to be sure from the photo alone because it looks like an 0603 package that are also commonly used by other passive components such as resistors and inductors.

You're right that sometimes they can live without a capacitor or two although it might lead to some stability problems. Sometimes that may only occur under obscure circumstances like at some temperarure ranges and when external inteference is present etc.

If it's been operating for some time without problems I think the chance of it causing any real damage are fairly slim but keep the component in a bag just in case you do need to get it repaired. Sometimes part of the component lead will tear off so they can't be re-soldered but having the old one will be important to identify what it is because you'll be unlikely to get a schematic for the motherboard.

If / when you want to get it repaired a general electronics / TV repair shop might be the best place to take it. Those packages are quite quick and easy to solder for someone with experience and the right gear so it shouldn't cost much.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the computer has operated a few days since the incident without any problems. Naturally I kept the capacitor and maybe I will request an offer from a local repair shop on the cost of the repair. Since the motherboard is not really a new model, I do not want to spend too much money on its repair.